# How to solve the Compile error <identifier> expected

Tags: java, identifier

I'm a fresher to java. When I compile the below code I got the errors in line 4,5,6. Would anyone explain the error and how to solve it...
Thanks a ton...

```
class Box{
    int length; //line 1
    int width; //line 2
    int height; //line 3

    length=13; //line 4
    width=3; //line 5
    height=8; //line 6
}
```

Comment: Assignments don't belong in the class body. Use an initialization block, a constructor, or a method for that.

Comment: You are declaring class fields with lines 1,2 and 3. Instead of assigning on different lines you can initialize variables in same place and/or you can use constructors/methods.

Comment: Here take a look at this link about classes, you should read all chapters to get a good grasp on classes. https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_class_attributes.asp